# Cannot write in the console after writing in the file

Tags: c#, console

I am trying to write in the file using console. Successfully i completed it. But the problem is, **I cannot write in the console after closing the connection between my file.** I properly disconnected with the file. Is there any problem in my code???

```
        var outfilename = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "name.txt");
        var outname = new StreamWriter(outfilename);
        Console.SetOut(outname);

        Console.WriteLine("aiiii");
        outname.Close();
        Console.SetOut(new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput()));

        Console.Write("hai");
        string nam1=Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(nam1);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
StreamWriter standardOutput = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
standardOutput.AutoFlush = true;
Console.SetOut(standardOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the default Output writer and reset it:

```
var defaultOut = Console.Out;

var outfilename = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "name.txt");
var outname = new StreamWriter(outfilename);
Console.SetOut(outname);

Console.WriteLine("aiiii");
outname.Close();
Console.SetOut(defaultOut);

Console.Write("hai");
string nam1 = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(nam1);
Console.ReadLine();
```